# How to start a task for a Twisted ServerFactory?

Tags: python, task, twisted, factory

I have a Twisted [ServerFactory](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory.html), which I started with [listenTCP](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.listenTCP.html). How do I start a task that is a function of that factory?
I tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    factory = MyFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(555558, factory)
    reactor.connectTCP("127.0.0.1", 55555, MyConnector(factory))

    sanitizing = task.LoopingCall(factory.sanitize())
    sanitizing.start(3, False)

    reactor.run()
```

But that throws an error:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in        runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 218, in __call__
    d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 139, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The factory is actually listening, so I don't understand why it is NoneType.

Comment: Please, put more details... And maybe would be nice to put code for MyFactory and MyConnector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `name()` is the syntax to call an object (usually a function or method).  By extension, `name(another_name())` is how you call an object (referenced by the name `another_name`) and then pass the return value of that call to another object (referenced by the name `name`).

To apply this to your example, `LoopingCall(factory.sanitize())` is how you call `factory.sanitize` and pass the return value to `LoopingCall`.

This is most likely not what you meant.  Instead, you probably meant to pass `factory.sanitize` as an argument to `LoopingCall`.  This is what you would need to do if you wanted `LoopingCall` to call `factory.sanitize` periodically, anyway.  I'm just guessing this is what you want - you didn't actually explicitly say what you want in your question. :)

Comment: You are completely right. The problem is actually unrelated to Twisted. The corresponding line should be
`sanitizing = task.LoopingCall(factory.sanitize)`